# Pass cmd commands via php script

Tags: php

Here is my php code

```
$command = "C:\Program Files\ClustalW2>clustalw2 -INFILE=seq.txt -TYPE=Protein -OUTFILE=res.aln";
exec($command);
```

When i run the command using the cmd, it generates the desired file. However when i try passing the same command via my php code it generates no result. How do i fix this problem?

Comment: try using back tick operator ` try this http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php

Comment: Probably you don't have permission to run this command from a PHP Script......

Comment: @Mian_Khurram_Ijaz: i am new to php, so wud like to knw wats the differnce between the two? And wat may the problems in using exec()??

Comment: @SayemAhmed: what do u mean by no permission to run this command??

Comment: @Nikita: You want to run a command on the `cmd`. Doing so required user privileges from the operating systems. Are you sure you can run this command from your web app in the host machine? Does the web app have sufficient privileges granted to it?

Comment: for that purpose i posted you the link to the back tick operator you do need to read that yourself and test / see if that solves your problem

Comment: @SayemAhmed: I dnt want to run a command on cmd. I want to run the cmd command using my php script. Also how do i check if i hv the previlege for running this command

Comment: @Mian_Khurram_Ijaz: I tried with the back tick operator as well, bt still it generates no result!

Comment: @Nikita: http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php#101837

Comment: does the external programe you trying to run is available on the path ?

Comment: @Mian_Khurram_Ijaz: ya the clustalw2 program is available on that path

Comment: Are you sure files are not created? what is your current working directory? Try to pass absolute path to -INFILE and -OUTFILE parameters.Also escape path to executable file so "c:\Program files" become "C:\\Program files" etc...

Comment: @rkosegi: Yes I'm sure the files are not created. Both the clustal.exe and my text file are in the C:\Program files directory. Also i tried escaping the path, but still it doesnt work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably it's because of the `>` symbol before executable's filename? Also, try with single quotes:

```
$command = 'C:\Program Files\ClustalW2\clustalw2 -INFILE=seq.txt -TYPE=Protein -OUTFILE=res.aln';
exec($command, $output, $retval);
var_dump($output);
var_dump($retval);
```

Comment: I tried what u have suggested but it still doesnt work. Also the single quotes make no difference..

Comment: @Nikita Do you see any warnings/errors? Try running modified version of the code snippet